# Best IDE for Javascrjpt dev on Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, macos, debugging, autocomplete, ide

I am new to development in javascript (I will also be coding in ReactJS  and WebGL), but not to coding in general (Java/C for Java I have used VisualCafe and Eclipse).  I have looked at preceding questions about IDEs and javascript, but I do not see a recent post so therefore I am posting this question as IDEs and plugins change.

Currently I am using Sublime (without a plugin) and stepping through my code with Chrome's developer tools, but I am wondering if there is a better IDE (or even if people favor Sublime with a plugin ?) that supports tab completion and general IDE support, and is strong for debugging.  I am not in need of a visual interface, as I prefer to code myself.

So the questions : 
What is free or cheap that people enjoy using ?
What is the best ?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: [Visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) provides good extensions for JavaScript

Comment: For me the best IDE for Javascript is: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/